# Are registry identities still supported on Windows 2012?

Tags: windows, iis, server

just trying to figure out if this is still supported.   Our app runs fine when I have identity stored in the web.config.   But, when I try to encrypt the string and store the userName password in the registry, I get an "Error reading configuration information from the registry".

Now, I have exported from Wow6432 and reimported into the regular spots.

I also granted the rights to both trees to Network Service, shoot, even on a whim, I granted rights to "Everyone" to the same trees, still get the same errors.

Now the kicker is, under Windows 2008R2, Eveything I'm doing worked fine.

So, anybody got any ideas on what I'm missing?

I'm sure it's something stupid on my part.

Comment: Nothing changed in 2012 in this regard, it should still work. Use `Process Monitor` to check access to your registry keys.

Answer (score 0):

Shoot, I know I did that, but yes, it was a rights issue to the tree in the registry.   Maybe it was just a kick in the butt that I needed....

Thanks!

Nick